# Simple basic verification problem in uppal

Tags: verification, uppaal

I'm struggling with some simple verification. I have automata and value x like this:

[image: automata]
[automata2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ppF26.png)

When x at the start is different from 0 then E<> x !=0 is satisfied, but when x = 0, then its not satisfied and E<> x == 0 and A<> x == 0 are satisfied.
But I would like to get a not satisfied for E<> x !=0 even when x is different from 0 at the start.

What should I change? How does that verify-er works exactly? Empty path, when nothing was executed is a correct path too? And the Set of all possibly paths contains this empty path as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial state is a state like any other, thus if x is 0 in the initial state, then all paths starting in this state will eventually be in a state where `x = 0` holds. If you want to check if `x = 0` in any other state, you need to exclude the initial state in the query. For instance `E<> x=0 and not line1.S0`.

Comment: Ty for answer it solved a problem with E<>, but I'm still strugling with A<>. You can find another screenshot in the definition. How is that what you see on screenshot even possible?

Comment: @RobertRuska The A<> case has to do with clocks. Since there is nothing that forces progress the automaton may stay indefinitely in the S0 location and in this case it will never reach a state where `x==0 and not line1.S0` holds.